# method write in bufferedwriter not accepting arguments

Tags: java

This is my java code in which I get the error described after code.

```
     import java.util.Scanner;
     import java.util.StringTokenizer;
     import java.io.*;
       import java.util.*;
       public class FileDemo {
public static void main(String args[]){
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter no of persons");
      int person=sc.nextInt();
      File myfile = new File("E:/java/myfile.txt");
      BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myfile));
     for(int i=0;i<person;i++)
     {

         System.out.println("Enter Firstname");
         String firstname=sc.next();

         System.out.println("Lastname");
         String lastname=sc.next();
         System.out.println("mobnum");
         int mobnum=sc.nextInt();

         output.write("+firstname+" "+lastname+" "+mobnum+");            
     }
     output.close();
      /*** here change fis to Reader ***/
   FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fis);
     int i=1;
   String str=null;
        while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
      {

    System.out.println("Person"+i);
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(str,"");

    System.out.println("FirstName"+st.nextToken());
    System.out.println("lastname"+st.nextToken());
    System.out.println("country"+st.nextToken());
      }
     }
    }
```

Here I'm getting error that The method write(String) in the type Writer is not applicable for the arguments (String,String).

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised you're getting that exact error if your code really looks like this:

```
output.write("+firstname+" "+lastname+" "+mobnum+");
```

The problem here is that you've got three string literals, so your code is a bit like this:

```
output.write("x" "y" "z")
```

That's simply invalid Java. I suspect you *actually* wanted:

```
output.write(firstname + " " + lastname + " " + mobnum);
```

Now you're performing string concatenation between five strings:

- `firstname`
- A space
- `lastname`
- A space
- `mobnum`

... which is what you intended, I believe. It's important to pay close attention to your code - you can't just start adding `"+` everywhere that you want to do string concatenation.

Comment: i want the output will be like this   firstname lastname mobnum           in the same line..

Comment: @karna: Yes, and that's what the code I've given will do - or rather, it'll write the *values* of `firstname`, `lastname` and `mobnum` on the same line. I assume you did actually want the values of the variables, rather than the actual text "firstname lastname mobnum"?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double quotes before `firstname` and after `mobnum`, use it like this:

```
output.write(firstname + " " + lastname + " " + mobnum);
```

The way you use it is like having 3 separated strings:

```
"+firstname+" "+lastname+" "+mobnum+" 

equals to => "string1" "string2" "string3"
```

Comment: thank you.. in the above program i'm getting another error at, FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fis);                           asking that change the fis to Reader..

Comment: You need an InputStreamReader between the BufferedReader and the FileInputStream, like: FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

Answer (score 1):

Your method call isn't correct. Use

```
output.write(firstname+" "+lastname+" "+mobnum);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `output.write()` has error

```
output.write(firstname+" "+lastname+" "+mobnum);
```

You should provide the full path in `FileInputStream` also

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("E:/java/myfile.txt");
```